# CloudRun Suddenly got `Improper path /cloudsql/{SQL_CONNECTION_NAME} to connect to Postgres Cloud SQL instance "{SQL_CONNECTION_NAME}"`

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, typeorm, google-cloud-run

We have been running a service using NestJS and TypeORM on fully managed CloudRun without issues for several months. Yesterday PM we started getting `Improper path /cloudsql/{SQL_CONNECTION_NAME} to connect to Postgres Cloud SQL instance "{SQL_CONNECTION_NAME}"` errors in our logs.

We didn't make any server/SQL changes around this timestamp. Currently there is no impact to the service so we are not sure if this is a serious issue.

This error is not from our code, and our third party modules shouldn't know if we use Cloud SQL, so I have no idea where this errors come from.

My assumption is Cloud SQL Proxy or any SQL client used in Cloud Run is making this error. We use --add-cloudsql-instances flag when deploying with "gcloud run deploy" CLI command.

Link to the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188462249)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This log was recently added in the Cloud Run data path to provide more context for debugging CloudSQL connectivity issues. However, the original logic was overly aggressive, emitting this message even for properly working CloudSQL connections. Your application is working correctly and should not receive this warning.

Thank you for reporting this issue. The fix is ready and should roll out soon. You should not see this message anymore after the fix is out.

Comment: I see this too in my logs, we were really scared

Comment: This error causes our monitoring system to get crazy. Now we can not distinguish between real errors and this one. Can we know when this fix will be rolled out?

Comment: Can confirm, BPM was sky high this morning.

Comment: Can confirm as well, seeing a ton of these messages but the connection is working just fine.

Comment: Same happening here
@urosp can you confirm when the fix will be rolled out?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. This has rolled out around 5/29, please let me know if you still see any issues.